# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property

Tags: javascript, asp.net

From the start of my code writing I set a Local message trap, in case of sending messages to the user. The trap is that.

```
Dim message As String = Nothing
        message = "bla bla bla"
        UserBirthDate.Text = Nothing
        LocalErrorMessage("InnerMessages", message)
        btnClr.Visible = True
        Return

Public Sub LocalErrorMessage(DivID As String, Message As String)
        errorCall = False
        Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()
        Dim innerMess As String = Message
        Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        Dim script As String = "InnerMessages('" + DivID + "', '" + innerMess + "')"
        If Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "MessageDiv") Then
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "MessageDiv", script, True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

I also set a small java script at the start of my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InnerMessages(TagID, mess) {
        document.getElementById(TagID).innerHTML = mess + '<br/><hr/>'; 
      }
    </script>
```

The all issue working fine... and I have to continue writing my code (which is a user registration page). Everything goes fine until today... When I saw a message once... and works fine... since this time never works again...
Always throw me the error

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

So I set another script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = getTag()
    function getTag() {
        var pWin = window.parent.document;
        return pWin;
    }
```

And I was modify the initial one

```
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function InnerMessages(TagID, mess) {
    var myTD = getTag();
    var t = myTD.forms.Form.childNodes;
    var s = t['355'].childNodes['0'].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById(TagID).innerHTML = mess + '<br/><hr/>'; 
      }
    </script>
```

That works once or twice... but not any more...
I can't understand why that happen...

Is there someone how can assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use the following script to solve my issue

```
<asp:Panel ID="ErrorPanel" runat="server" CssClass="RegErrPanel" Enabled="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        <div id="LocalMessages" runat="server" title="LocalError Messages" class="regErrorDiv">
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function InnerMessages(TagID, mess) {
                 var t = window.document.forms.Form.getElementsByTagName('div')
                 t[TagID].innerHTML = mess + '<br/><hr/>';
             }
         </script> 
         </div>
         <br /><br />
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="RegisterValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="RegValidSummary" ValidationGroup="SetUserValGroup" ForeColor="Red" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnClr" runat="server" Text="Καθαρισμός"  Visible="false"  OnClientClick="<%btnClr_Click%>" CssClass="RegErrCleanUp" />
        </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: You've got a mix of front-end and back-end code, this isn't very clean and may be hard to read in the future. Not to criticize just something to be weary of. Also this: OnClientClick="<%btnClr_Click%>" should probably be <%= btnClr_Click %> but we can't really tell from the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that document.getElementById(TagID) is actually returning an object. It looks like you might be using ASP.Net which can change the id. And/Or it could be a timing issue. Where the element does exist but not at the time of the execution of the code. To resolve this do not execute the javascript code until some event has passed (document.onload or jQuery has a .ready)

This code example solves the timing issue and the changing id.

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
    //code here executes after the page is loaded    
    $("#textBox1").val("This might not work, as the id of the control might have changed.");
    $("input[id$='textBox1']").val("This is more likely to work since asp prefixes the id");
    $(".someClass").val("Using a css class is more a more  typical jQuery approach");
    $("<%= textBox1.ClientID %>").val("Force asp.net to fix the id, however (see below)")
}
```

- The problem with the last approach is that your aspx file now has C# in it. This can lead to other problems and considered a bad design.

Comment: Yes I am using ASP.NET. In onload jquery I sould looking for pWin = window.ready? in a loop like while - next??? or!

Comment: I'm going to adjust my comment so as to get the code formatting correct.

Comment: Hooo yes it is a problem with that... Well finally I solve my issue which it works in other objects as well... like Images... where in the place of 'div' I set 'asp:Image'... Thank you very much for your efforts.